Nextjs with nodemailer error 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
I'm trying to configure sending an email via a form on Nodemailer. But I have this error: code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: ',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
The password indicated in my env are valid. Here is my code:
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { name, date, phone, time, guests, diet, children } = req.body;

    if (!process.env.EMAIL_USER || !process.env.EMAIL_PASS) {
      console.error('Les variables d\'environnement EMAIL_USER ou EMAIL_PASS ne sont pas définies');
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erreur de configuration du serveur' });
    }    

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'Mailjet',
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
      }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      to: 'cheeseburger369@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Nouvelle Réservation',
      text: `
        Nom: ${name}\n
        Date: ${date}\n
        Numéro de Téléphone: ${phone}\n
        Heure: ${time}\n
        Nombre de Couverts: ${guests}\n
        Régime Particulier: ${diet.join(', ')}\n
        Enfants: ${children}
      `,
    };

    try {
      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi de l\'email:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erreur lors de l\'envoi de l\'email' });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: 'Méthode non autorisée' });
  }
}

If anyone has an idea where the problem could come from?
I tried with yahoo and mailjet and it's the same error.

Okay the problem is yahoo remove app password since one year :
https://www.reddit.com/r/yahoo/comments/xz94ao/yahoo_generate_app_password_sorry_this_feature_is/
I use gmail instead and it works
